# Por que no nosso site não tem ícones em tags como no SOEN?

Tags: novo-recurso

Bem, eu vi isso no Stackoverflow em inglês e até que achei bonitinho:

[image: ícone na tag do stackoverflow english]

Por que o nosso site não tem ícone também nas tags?

É possível adicionar essa opção aqui no Stackoverflow em Portugues?